# Index on join and where

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlperformance

Given the next SQL statement:

```
Select * 
  from A join B
           on A.id1=B.id1 and 
              A.id2=B.id2
 where A.year=2016
   and B.year=2016
```

and knowing table `A` is much smaller than table `B`, so I need the database first to access `A` table by year, then join, then filter `B` table by year, my question is:

does it make sense to create an index over `B` like `(id1,id2,year)` for improve performance?

Many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The optimizer will push the WHERE conditions to the base tables and will ONLY read the rows with the "proper" years before it will do any joining. Do you have an index on "year" in both tables? THAT would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this query:

```
Select *
from A join
     B
     on A.id1 = B.id1 and A.id2 = B.id2
where A.year = 2016 and B.year = 2016;
```

I would suggest indexes on `A(year, id1, id2)` and `B(id1, id2, year)`.

You might also write the query as:

```
Select *
from A join
     B
     on A.id1 = B.id1 and A.id2 = B.id2 and A.year = B.year
where A.year = 2016;
```

The answer to your question is "yes" and index on `B` is the right thing to do.  In this version, the order of the columns in the index does not really matter.

Comment: But isn't B table' s index enough? Is the A table index necessary?

Comment: @Alex . . . The index on A is useful if filtering by year is useful.

Comment: Sorry, what i wanted to say was: isn't an index over year enough on table A? Is it necessary the composite on A?

Comment: @Alex . . . Well, it is sufficient.  By including the join columns in the index, the looking on the data page only needs to occur *after* the join rather than *before*.  I admit, though, that I don't know if Oracle implements this optimization.