# Distinct clause on large join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, distinct

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263316/index-on-join-and-where/41263373), suppose now I've set up the indexes, and now I want only to return certain field, without duplicates:

```
Select distinct A.cod 
  from A join B
       on A.id1=B.id1 and 
          A.id2=B.id2
 where A.year=2016
   and B.year=2016
```

the problem now is I'm getting something like 150k `cod`, with only 1000 distinct values, so my query is very inefficient.

Question: how can I improve that? i.e, how can I tell the DB, for every row on `A`, to stop joining that row as soon as a match is found?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show an explain plan.

Comment: You *don't* tell the DB how to implement your query.  Figuring out how to perform it efficiently is its job, and Oracle is pretty good at that job.  Supposing that your query is well-enough covered by indices, the best thing you can do is to make sure you have reasonably up-to-date database statistics.

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? Return the "codes" from table A, as long as the year is 2016, and there is a matching row in table B with the same year, id1 and id2? You should use an `IN` condition for this, which will not do a full join (and you will not need to do a DISTINCT either).

Comment: define "inefficient". 1000 uniques over 150k records is a very, very good ratio, supposing linear repartition over these. (in terms of index usefulness)

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing my answer on your question:

```
how can I tell the DB, for every row on A, to stop joining that row as soon as a match is found?
```

with the `EXISTS` clause, once it sees a match it will stop and check for the next record to be checked.
adding the `DISTINCT` will filter out any duplicate CODs (in case there is one).

```
select DISTINCT cod
from   A ax
where  year = 2016
and    exists ( select 1
                from   B bx
                WHERE  Ax.ID1 = Bx.ID1
                AND Ax.ID2 = Bx.ID2
                AND Ax.YEAR = Bx.YEAR);
```

EDIT: Was curious which solution (`IN` or `EXISTS`) will give me a better Explain plan

Create the 1st Table Definition
    Create table A
    (
        ID1  number,
        ID2  number,
        cod  varchar2(100),
        year number
    );

insert 4000000 sequential numbers

```
BEGIN

    FOR i IN 1..4000000 loop

        insert into A (id1, id2, cod, year)
        values (i, i , i, i);

    end loop;

END;

commit;
```

Create Table B and insert the same data into to it

```
Create table B
as
select  *
from    A;
```

Reinsert Data from Table A to make duplicates

```
insert into B
select  *
from    A
```

Build the Indexes mentioned in the Previous Post [Index on join and where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263316/index-on-join-and-where/41263373)

```
CREATE INDEX A_IDX ON A(year, id1, id2);
CREATE INDEX B_IDX ON B(year, id1, id2);
```

Update a bunch of rows to make it fetch multiple rows with the year 2016:

```
update B
set   year = 2016
where rownum < 20000;

update A
set   year = 2016
where rownum < 20000;

commit;
```

Check Explain plan using `EXISTS`

```
Plan hash value: 1052726981

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              |     1 |    44 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                  |              |     1 |    44 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS SEMI           |              |     1 |    44 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| A     |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | A_IDX |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | B_IDX |     2 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("YEAR"=2016)
   5 - access("BX"."YEAR"=2016 AND "AX"."ID1"="BX"."ID1" AND "AX"."ID2"="BX"."ID2")
       filter("AX"."YEAR"="BX"."YEAR")
```

Check Explain plan using `IN`

```
Plan hash value: 3002464630

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              |     1 |    44 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                  |              |     1 |    44 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |              |     1 |    44 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| A     |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | A_IDX |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | B_IDX |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

4 - access("YEAR"=2016)
5 - access("YEAR"=2016 AND "ID1"="ID1" AND "ID2"="ID2")
```

Although my test case is limited, i'm guessing that both the `IN` and `EXISTS` clause have nearly the same execution.

Comment: This is similar to the IN solution, but it has a disadvantage - since the subquery is correlated (it has WHERE conditions which change for each row in table A), it may need to be recalculated once for each row. In a simple query like the one here, the CBO may realize what is going on and rewrite it without the correlation (the plan may be identical to the plan for the IN solution), but in more complicated problems it may not be able to see that.

Comment: hey @mathguy, yes i saw your answer too. quite difficult to see which solution is better (`IN` or `EXISTS`) without the sample data. it may be up to OP to decide with his current data set.

Comment: @mathguy, i added some test cases, maybe you'd like to take a look.

Comment: As expected. There is the additional filter condition (`ax.year = bx.year`) in the execution plan for the EXISTS solution, but that's because you had the condition written as `bx.year = ax.year` instead of the simpler and more efficient `bx.year = 2016`. This results in just a little more overhead (very likely negligible). +1 and I'll remember you for the excellent work ethic - the willingness to do the tests, format the explain plans, discuss it all here. Big thumbs-up!

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, what you are actually trying to do should be done like this:

```
select distinct cod
from   A
where  year = 2016
  and  (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2 from B where year = 2016)
```

The subquery in the WHERE condition is a non-correlated query, so it will be evaluated only once. And the IN condition is evaluated using short-circuiting; instead of a complete join, it will search through the results of the subquery only until a match is found.

EDIT: As Migs Isip points out, there may be duplicate codes in the original table, so a "distinct" may still be needed. I edited my code to add it back after Migs posted his answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about your existing indexes but you can improve your query a bit by adding another `JOIN` condition like

```
Select distinct A.cod 
  from A join B
       on A.id1=B.id1 and 
          A.id2=B.id2 and
          A.year = B.year  // this one
 where A.year=2016;
```

Comment: ?? It is very likely that the CBO will "push the predicates" to the base tables *before* performing the join, so what's the difference?

Comment: I'm 99% sure your proposition will actually result into a worse explain plan

Comment: @sebas - actually, no - it will result in the same plan (at least in a simple query like the one here). The CBO will recognize this query as "the same" as the OP's query and it will develop the same plan. This was what I suspected; then I tested it, using the SCOTT schema and the EMP and DEPT tables, and indeed, the CBO performs that transformation - it replaces the last ON condition with the corresponding WITH condition, which it then pushes to the base table.

Comment: @mathguy OK thanks for the effort. I had bad memories of a query explain plan back then... I was certain it did change when I forced hardcoded values instead of joins